# Calling a table with a string

Tags: lua, lua-table

Alright I'll get straight to the point. I am currently working on a script for the RedM and I have run into a bit of trouble. I have a table I need to call but I need to be able to call it with a string and despite trying to figure this out for days I have had no luck. Here's a quick example of what I am trying to do.

```
Table = {
    "Value 1",
    "Value 2",
    "Value 3"
}


local _Table = "Table"
    for key, value in pairs(_Table) do
        print(value)
    end
```

What I am wanting that to do is print out everything in that table however when you try to use a string you get the following error

```
$lua main.lua
lua: main.lua:9: bad argument #1 to 'for iterator' (table expected, got string)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'next'
    main.lua:9: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

And obviously the script works when you don't use a string however that won't work for me. To be totally honest I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do is even possible, but if it is and anyone has a solution it would be VERY appreciated lol.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you cannot call a table unless its metatable implements `__call`. I assume you're confusing some basic terminology here.
2. your code doesn't make sense

```lua
-- this line assigns the string "Table" to _Table
local _Table = "Table"
-- now you put into pairs which may only take a table as input
for key, value in pairs(_Table) do
  print(value)
end
```

If `Table` is a global variable as in your example you can access it through the global environment table `_G`.

```
for key, value in pairs(_G.Table) do print(value) end
```

or

```
local _Table = "Table"
for key, value in pairs(_G[_Table]) do print(value) end
```

Comment: Hi there! I appreciate the response! To clarify some things, everything I know about lua is self taught by studying other scripts people have made so it is VERY possible I'm not using proper terminology so i apologize for any confusion that may have caused. The last suggestion you gave `(_G[_Table])` ended up being exactly what I was looking for so thanks for that!

Comment: maybe you should read the Lua manual rather than just other scripts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to get a table by its variable name. This is only possible at all if the variable is global, which it shouldn't (Always make your variables local, children) and even then it wouldn't be the most elegant solution.

A better alternative might be: put your tables in another table:

```lua
local Tables = {
   Table_1 = { 1, 2, 3, }
   Table_2 = { 2, 3, 4, }
}

print(Tables["Table_1"])
```

This keeps the global scope clean and allows you to pass the whole set of tables around as a single value.